# "Full blood Italian" or "full blooded Italian"?

Tags: word-choice

If I wanted to say I am 100% Italian, which of the following phrases should I use?

- Full blood Italian
- Full blooded Italian

The reason I am asking is that in Italian, I would use the equivalent of *blood*.

Comment: Related question on ELU, which I'm a bit nervous about summarizing: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70096/why-are-nouns-sometimes-pejorative-when-used-attributively

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use either form. They're both perfectly valid, and will be understood (with the caveat below about a potential misunderstanding). Here are usage figures from Google Books...

> [full-blood Eskimo](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=full%20blood%20italian&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22full%20blood%20eskimo%22&oq=%22full%20blood%20eskimo%22&gs_l=serp.3...90070.93880.3.94319.13.13.0.0.0.0.77.710.13.13.0...0.0...1c.1.8.psy-ab.rJyaSQPUpzU&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44770516,d.d2k&fp=2c7f7497fa4ec5c5&biw=1396&bih=822) - 893 results
>    [full-blooded Eskimo](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=full%20blood%20italian&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22full%20blooded%20eskimo%22&oq=%22full%20blooded%20eskimo%22&gs_l=serp.3...4571.4826.4.5447.2.2.0.0.0.0.44.84.2.2.0...0.0...1c.1.8.psy-ab.nJuoAe9iXvs&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44770516,d.d2k&fp=2c7f7497fa4ec5c5&biw=1396&bih=822)  - 3700 results

I chose to search for *Eskimo* rather than *Italian* because there's another sense to *full-blooded* that rarely applies to *full-blood*...

> [He let out a **full-blooded cry**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=full%20blood%20italian&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22full%20blooded%20cry%22&oq=%22full%20blooded%20cry%22&gs_l=serp.3...340071.341891.5.342314.9.9.0.0.0.0.112.502.8j1.9.0...0.0...1c.1.8.psy-ab.1tuuuH-oYVU&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44770516,d.d2k&fp=2c7f7497fa4ec5c5&biw=1396&bih=822)

...where the meaning is *forceful, whole-hearted* (closely related to ***hot***-blooded - inclined to powerful emotion, passionate; hot-tempered.) The stereotypical Italian is often portrayed as passionate/excitable, so there's more chance of *full-blooded **Italian*** being used with / understood as that second meaning.

To avoid any potential confusion/ambiguity, therefore, I'd advise going with ***full-blood Italian***. You'll be slightly in the minority (but not [in the wrong](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&q=in+the+wrong&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=yoxhUdn_GsbR0QXykIGIBg&ved=0CC0QkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44770516,d.d2k&fp=a7034d10d8282623&biw=1396&bih=872)), and your intended meaning will always be understood.

---

EDIT: Here are usage figures for a couple of similar constructions, showing that there's no "grammatical principle" involved in whether such "adjectival" usages are based on a noun *(blood)*, or verb *(blooded)*...

> [soft-top car](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22soft%20top%20car%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (665); [soft-topped car](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22soft%20top%20car%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22soft%20topped%20car%22&oq=%22soft%20topped%20car%22&gs_l=serp.3...4892.5452.0.5934.3.3.0.0.0.0.109.251.1j2.3.0...0.0...1c.1.8.psy-ab.rclZKEHSjaM&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44770516,d.d2k&fp=2c7f7497fa4ec5c5&biw=1396&bih=872) (40)
>    [warm-blood animals](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22warm%20blood%20animals%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (3K); [warm-blooded animals](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22warm%20blood%20animals%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22warm%20blooded%20animals%22&oq=%22warm%20blooded%20animals%22&gs_l=serp.3...4951.5148.0.5810.2.2.0.0.0.0.177.237.1j1.2.0...0.0...1c.1.8.psy-ab.CXDkAEGmNW4&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44770516,d.d2k&fp=2c7f7497fa4ec5c5&biw=1396&bih=872) (190K)

Comment: Though I don't doubt you that 'full-blood' is correct, I do have to say that I've never heard it said that way, and that until I read your post I'd have said it was incorrect. This could also perhaps be a US/UK distinction, I'm not sure. But this has been my experience, at any rate.

Comment: @WendiKidd♦: More likely a regional variation in your area, I think. As [this NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=full+blood%2Cfull+blooded&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=) shows, *full-blood* is more common overall in both the US and the UK. It's true that *he was a full-blood Indian* (which is more likely to occur in the US than UK) has only 11 hits (as against 26 for *he was a full-blooded Indian*), but it surprises me that you weren't even aware of the "somewhat less common" usage.

Comment: ...the corresponding figures for *I am a full-blood/blooded Indian* are 14/18. They're both used sufficiently often that I wouldn't distinguish them at all except for the "alternative meaning" caveat above.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "Full blood" can be used as an independent noun, while "full blooded" cannot.  For your conclusion to be valid, you need to count attributive uses of "full blood", not total uses.

Comment: @snailplane: I don't see why it makes any difference exactly how many instances of *full-blood* are "noun" usages. Both my Eskimo examples are clearly "adjectival", and will almost always mean *genetically pure*. My point is simply that whereas both forms are in fact used, *full-blooded* is potentially ambiguous. As proved by, for example, [full-blooded fighter](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22full-blooded+fighter%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), where it always means *feisty*. So you may as well choose the unambiguous variant when you mean *thoroughbred*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I didn't mean that *full-blood* isn't a valid answer.  I just meant that you can't draw that conclusion ("is more common overall in both the US and the UK") from the n-grams you charted, as they include uses that aren't relevant to the discussion.

Comment: @snailplane: oic - you mean the NGram in my comment. Like I say, I don't think it's really important which is more common *specifically when used adjectivally*, since clearly they're both used that way. And if I search for typical nouns that might be thus modified *(Italian, Negro, Indian)* unavoidably that will drag in some instances where *full-blooded* has the more "figurative" sense. With a "mongrel" race like [full-blooded Englishman](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22full-blooded+Englishman%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), probably *most* instances are at least partly figurative.

Answer (score 4):

**Full-blooded** is an adjective (with the hyphen) meaning **thoroughbred** or *through both parents*. Either of the following should be correct.

- I am a full-blooded Italian.
- I am an Italian and a full-blood.

Answer (score 1):

I would say

> I'm a full-blooded Italian.